# Visual Studio 2005 Add-in Project Template

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to find a way to develop my own Add-in in C# for Visual Studio 2005 at home, but I don't have the template that comes in the full version of the VS2005.

If I get the template, can I compile it on the Express edition?

Does anyone have it? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment specifically on the Add-in Project template, but I know that the Express version of Visual Studio doesn't have the template for Windows Services, but also doesn't have the required libraries (System.ServiceProcess) to be able to compile a Windows Service project.

A trial of VS 2005 might be hard to come by these days, but have you tried downloading a trial of VS 2010 and, if you need to, targeting the .NET 2.0 framework?

Comment: Well, It would be good to use VS2010, but I can't do that right now.

The thing is, I have a bunch of XML files in my project that defines my software behavior. Each file have its "Custom tool" property set to the app I created to parse the XML and create automatized C# code.

I tried to create pre-build events, but since there are A LOT of XMLs, it increases the build time for about 30 minutes.

I wish I could develop a plug-in in order check if the generated code is updated or not before calling the code factory on the outdated files.